# React native navigation tab logout function

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

So I have a react native app and I am using react-navigation tab navigator. My problem is I put my Logout function on the tab navigator too, but each tab requires a screen. Now what I want to happen is when I click Logout it doesn't have to navigate anywhere it just have to clear asyncstorage then redirect to Login screen.

Thanks in advance!

**P.S. I am new to react-native.**

Comment: Just a semantic/UX comment: Usually you wouldn't have a logout button in a tab navigator. You'd probably have a profile tab then have a logout button on that screen.

Comment: Yeah I agree. But i'm just following the design :)

Comment: Can you explain a bit the problem what i am getting from this is that you need the whole working code for what you are describing and not a solution ... Give us some info like Do you use redux? Some code example etc... thanks

Comment: @PanagiotisVrs Yeah you're right I need the whole thing. I don't know how to do it. I'm not yet using redux but based on researching it seems that it's what I need. But still I don't know how to use it. I am using react navigation and the design I'm following puts the Logout link on the tab navigator which is hard because as far as I know, tab navigators only accepts screen and not events.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you have logged in your user and store his info with AsyncStorage (session).

1) What i would do with react-navigation or react-native-router-flux is to load a component that on componentWillMount() function will trigger the logout function and redirect him on the scene you need. See the example below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation'
import { logoutUser } from '../actions/index' //Action from Redux

class LogoutScene extends Component {
  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.logoutUser()
    NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: someRouteName })
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {logoutUser})(LogoutScene)
```

2) I highly recommend for you to use Redux on your project because although is hard and makes no sense at the beginning of a project in the long term makes your life so easy. In order to do though you will need something more than the above example. I think you should check this https://medium.com/@jonlebensold/getting-started-with-react-native-redux-2b01408c0053

Let me know if this makes sense

Comment: I'm not able to resolve this yet, but I have another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46675964/react-navigation-changing-tab-icons-on-tab-navigator-dynamically maybe after this I can apply your answer. Thanks