# React Navigation changing tab icons on tab navigator dynamically

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux, react-navigation

So I am new to react native and `redux`. The app is already configured (by someone else) to have `react-navigation` and `redux`. Now we're using a `TabNavigator` (bottom) for our menu and this `TabNavigator` also contains the Login button. Now what I want to do is when the user logs in, the Login button (with text and icon) becomes Logout.

Is there a way to do that? Also my `TabNavigator` is in a separate file.

What I want is something like this:

```
TabNavigator(
  {
    ...other screens,
    //show this only if not logged in
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen
    },
    //show this only if logged in
    Logout: {
      screen: //There should be no screen here just the logout functionality
    }
  },
  {...options here}
)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Redux:

AuthIcon.js:

```
const LOGGED_IN_IMAGE = require(...)
const LOGGED_OUT_IMAGE = require(...)

class AuthIcon extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { loggedIn, focused, tintColor } = this.props
     // loggedIn is what tells your app when the user is logged in, you can call it something else, it comes from redux
    return (
       <View>
         <Image source={loggedIn ? LOGGED_IN_IMAGE : LOGGED_OUT_IMAGE} resizeMode='stretch' style={{ tintColor: focused ? tintColor : null, width: 21, height: 21 }} />
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const ConnectedAuthIcon = connect(state => {
   const { loggedIn } = state.auth
   return { loggedIn }
})(AuthIcon)

export default ConnectedAuthIcon;
```

then inside your TabNavigator file:

```
import ConnectedAuthIcon from './AuthIcon.js'

export default TabNavigator({
  Auth: {
    screen: Auth,
    navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
      tabBarLabel: null,
      tabBarIcon: ({ tintColor, focused }) => <ConnectedAuthIcon tintColor={tintColor} focused={focused} />,
      title: "Auth"
    })
  }
})
```

Edit:

In your Auth.js:

```
class Auth extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { loggedIn } = this.props
    if (loggedIn) {
      return <Profile />
    } else {
      return <Login />
    }
  }

}

export default connect(state => {
  const { loggedIn } = state.auth
  return { loggedIn }
})(Auth)
```

Comment: How about the corresponding screen for that icon? I mean the actions when it's login and the action when it's logout.

Comment: Easy. Your Auth component will be connected to redux too and if loggedIn is true it will render the profile otherwise login. Profile and Login can be separate components and you conditionally render the corresponding one in Auth

Comment: Sorry I am new to redux and react navigation so I have no idea what you just said. It will be very much appreciated if you can show an example. :) I apologize for the trouble.

Comment: There's a difference of you example on my question, it's that when the user is logged in there should be no screen but just the Logout tab which is why I couldn't find an exact sample online. On your sample when the user is logged in there's a Profile screen.

Comment: Also, I also need the text on the tab to be either Login or Logout, on your sample you're just changing the icon.